# How do I format this return?

Tags: python

I have this function that generate the initial population for a genetic algorithm.

```
import random


def initial_pop(pop_size):
    pop = list()
    for i in range(pop_size):
        aux = list()
        for j in range(2):
            signal = bin(random.randint(0, 1))[2:].zfill(1)
            int_part = bin(random.randint(0, 2))[2:].zfill(2)
            real_part = bin(random.randint(0, 5000))[2:].zfill(13)
            x = ''.join([signal, int_part, real_part])
            aux.append(x)
        pop.append(aux)
    return pop


population = initial_pop(5)
print(population)
```

The function returns something like this:

> [['1001000001111101', '1100111001001010'], ['0000111110100111', '0011001000100011'], ['1000010101001101', '0000101001100011'], ['1100000011011010', '0011000010001110'], ['0100010101001010', '1001000010001110']]

And I have this function that make the crossover between parents:

```
def crossover(pai1, pai2, cross_rate):
    p1x = pai1[0]
    p1y = pai1[1]
    p2x = pai2[0]
    p2y = pai2[1]
    if np.random.rand() < tx_cruzamento:
        f1x = p1x[:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_1] + p2x[PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_1:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_2] + p1x[:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_2]
        f1y = p1y[:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_1] + p2y[PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_1:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_2] + p1y[:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_2]
        f2x = p2x[:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_1] + p1x[PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_1:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_2] + p2x[:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_2]
        f2y = p2y[:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_1] + p1y[PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_1:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_2] + p2y[:PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_2]
        f1 = [f1x] + [f1y]
        f2 = [f2x] + [f2y]
        return [f1] + [f2]
    else:
        return [pai1] + [pai2]
```

The call for this function is:

> children.append(crossover(selected[j], selected[j+1], CROSS_RATE))

However, this function return something like this:

> [[['1100101011000010', '1101100011010000'], ['1010001010101010', '1010000010101000']], [['1010101011010010', '1010100011001100'], ['1100010000100001', '1011000111101000']], [['1100010011000010', '1101000111010000'], ['1100001011000100', '1011000010110001']]]

How do I format the output to look exactly like the first one? The one that generated the initial population? I tried everything ([f1] + [f2], [[f1]+[f2]], [f1, f2], etc)

Comment: How about `return [f1x] + [f1y] + [f2x] + [f2y]`, or equivalently, `return f1 + f2`.

Comment: Have you tried `f1 + f2`?  They are already `list`s, so you don't need to wrap in an extra set of brackets.

Comment: @0x5453 - Ha.  Great minds think alike ;)

Comment: Both answers return [['1001001110010000', '1001010010010010', '0100000001000011', '1000001010000100'], ['0100100101000011', '1000001010000100', '0000001100001001', '0001010000010010'], ['1001100110010000', '1001001010010010', '0000000000001001', '0001001000010010']] but I need [['1001000001111101', '1100111001001010'->]<-, ['0000111110100111', '0011001000100011'] (I maked the missing bracket with -> <-)

Comment: Could you make this a [mcve] which can be run as is? The code that you posted depends upon things which are defined elsewhere. Also is `cross_rate` supposed to be `tx_cruzamento` (or vice-versa)?

Comment: @JohnColeman yes, I forgot to translate. So, the minimum population is 2 (because I need 2 parents). The expected output is `[['0000011101000010', '1010000100001000'], ['1100101101000011', '0010111101110100']]`, f1+f2 is returning `[['0100000001000110', '1100010011001110', '1100011011000000', '0100111001000100']]`

Comment: What is the value of things like `PONTO_CRUZAMENTO_1`?

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm performing a two-point crossover, it's just 2 random values in the len of the chromossome where I swap bits from father 1 and 2 to generate the childrens. Like this [link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/TwoPointCrossover.svg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in how `selected` is defined. When I call your cross-over function like this:

```
crossover(population[0],population[1],0.3)
```

I get output which looks like:

```
[['0000110000101001', '1010100101111111'], ['0010101110111110', '0001001010110001'], ['0100100110000010', '0100111100011001'], ['0011000100010010', '0010110110111111'], ['0010010111000110', '0010010101111011']]
[['0000110000101001', '1010100101111111'], ['0010101110111110', '0001001010110001']]
```

which matches the form of your intended output.

This suggests that the problem lies with code that you didn't show. Alternatively, `crossover` needs to do some preprocessing to extract the data that it needs from that which is passed to it. If this isn't the case, you really need to provide the missing details that would allow others to replicate the problem.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I was too focused in the crossover function that I forgot to check selected. It was returning [[[01010, 010110]], [010101, 10010]]... or something like this, thanks, I appreciate you're help